# Interstitial Admob doesn't work : AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial

I have two kind of ads : banner and interstitial. The first one works very well, but when I want to display an interstitial ad when I pressed the back button (but we don't care of the button), before closing my app. But my interstitial ad doesn't work and my app is closing with this error in log :

```
E/Ads(20984): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined (:1)
```

I don't know what this error means.
I browsed internet, and it may comes from my internet connection. My Wifi ?
Or it might comes from Admob aswell ?

Should I try in an other area with a better connexion ?

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My code use to add InterstitialAdd:

```
public static void addInterstitialAd(final Activity context, final int id) {
    final InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(context);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(context.getString(id));
    interstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Call displayInterstitial() function
            if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                interstitial.show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You can try it if not work, please separate to new thread:

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        final InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(context);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(context.getString(id));
        interstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Call displayInterstitial() function
                if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    interstitial.show();
                }
              });                
             }
            }
        });
     }
    }).start();
```

If your want after click back -> Admod-> close admod -> apclose:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        final InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(getApplicationContext());
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(getApplicationContext().getString(id));
        interstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Call displayInterstitial() function
                if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                    interstitial.show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed(){
                finish();
            }
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode){
                //you can implement continue load or finish 
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: I tried both. The first one didn't made error in logs. I even have "ads opening" but then nothing happened, the app still closing as before, whitout the interstitial. And the second one, I have error in logs, and my app is crashing. I think i'm doing wrong with the " context " . What am I supposed to write there ?
I tried " MainAcitivy.getContext() " which is where my function are. But also " gridview.getContext() " which is the only parent in my layout.

Any help @mdtuyen ?

Comment: I answered below @mdtuyen.

Comment: you only add code code app when Ads closed, or error. Change in manifest file ` <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />`

Comment: Yes that's it ! I was coming back here to tell you that I just add android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/> and it's working ! 
Thank you very much man !

Comment: @Slamingzone i am facing same error.
If i use my old ID ads will show up. but new ids showing me balnk ads.
Can u help me out from this

Answer (score 0):

Do not place interstitial ads on app load and when exiting apps as interstitials should only be placed in between pages of app content.