# Unable to display AdMob Banner

Tags: android, admob, banner, uncaught-exception, referenceerror

I am trying to ad using AdMob to display ads at the bottom of screen.

I added following line in my build.gradle file to get AdMob sdk:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
```

After then, I added AdView in XML to show ads:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

Now I make a referecne of AdView using ad_view id and build AdRequest to request for ads using following lines of code:

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
//  .addTestDevice("38C0F116926519A0CBAF1094898921FB")
    .build();

if (mAdView != null)
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Everything works perfect if I uncomment `addTestDevice` function but when I try to display real ads, I am getting the following error in logcat:

```
12-23 17:18:02.234 13226-13226/com.abc.xyz I/Ads: Starting ad request.
12-23 17:18:02.234 13226-13226/com.abc.xyz I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("38C0F116926519A0CBAF1094898921FB") to get test ads on this device.
12-23 17:18:02.554 13226-13226/com.abc.xyz I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42dd86b8 time:83516183
12-23 17:18:05.694 13226-13226/com.abc.xyz D/EgretLoader: EgretLoader(Context context)
12-23 17:18:05.694 13226-13226/com.abc.xyz D/EgretLoader: The context is not activity
12-23 17:18:05.764 13226-13226/com.abc.xyz I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
12-23 17:18:05.824 13226-13226/com.abc.xyz E/Ads: JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined (:1)
12-23 17:18:05.824 13226-13226/com.abc.xyz I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined", source:  (1)
```

After searching the issue, I tried the solutions from the below links but none of them worked for me.

[Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717358/uncaught-referenceerror-afma-getsdkconstants-is-not-defined)

[Interstitial Admob doesn't work : AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906862/interstitial-admob-doesnt-work-afma-receivemessage-is-not-defined)

Please suggest me what I am doing wrong or what I am missing. Thanks.

Comment: can you post your entire layout xml which has adview

Comment: sometimes it takes time, and you should also try  on another device then problem will be solved

Comment: the error code  number

Comment: @Androider yes you are right, using the same code now all the real ads appear in my adview. Thanks all for help. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I check your code and is correct, some times you have to do 2 things:

1-  Wait for check, remember  you just add the ad a few minutes ago.
2- Try in a real device, remember you dont have the same stuff like play store servies in a emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing a similar issue. In my case on moving the AdView xml content from activity_main.xml to content_main.xml resolved the problem.

Comment: please elaborate more details, what is the difference between activity_main and content_main?