# AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined using APPODEAL

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to integrate APPODEAL banner ad with my app and this error is appearing in my logcat:

```
E/Ads: JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined
```

I tried to do this: [AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119062/afma-receivemessage-is-not-defined) but the error message is still showing up and im not able to see any banner ad.
My dependencies on build.gradle looks like this:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':unity-ads-1.5.3')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
```

}

And my banner show code that is on the onCreate() method of my main activity:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Appodeal.initialize(MainActivity.this, appKey, Appodeal.BANNER);
            Appodeal.show(MainActivity.this, Appodeal.BANNER_BOTTOM);
        }
    }).start();
```

The permissions on the manifest are these:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and the bundle_id matches with the one that is on the APPODEAL. Can anyone tell what is going on or what that means ?

--------------------EDIT----------------------

I just found out on this google groups discussion:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-admob-ads-sdk/AFMA/google-admob-ads-sdk/LVnmBbQd2l4/47T8Xn0SAgAJ

That (in my case) it was a problem with newly created ad units.
24h past the creation and it is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"` added to the activity declaration in your manifest as follows:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" 
     android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|s‌​creenSize|smallestScreenSize" 
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

This seems to have fixed the problem for someone as per the [comments on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33907502/1957401)

Also try to include the entire GMS library in your dependency and see if that works:

Replace:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
```

With:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
```

Comment: My manifest is just as the APPODEAL asks [link](http://www.appodeal.com/sdk/documentation?framework=1&full=1) (it also have other informations about my activities, etc). I replaced my dependencies but the error is still showing up

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have created seperate Ad Unit ID for interstitial. If you use banner Ad Unit ID for interstitial request, this exact same error happens.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it might be connected with separate ad units for definite ad formats, as mentioned above. Anyway i'd suggest contacting their support via chat on the homepage you'll see there a Chat-icon. I had a technical issue and it was fixed within an hour, so it seems to be more effective to reach out one of their specialists directly. Cheers!