# AdMob InterstitialAd "AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined" vs "must be called on the main UI thread"

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial

I am trying to implement Iterstitial Ads from AdMob. I managed to get it displayed in Test Mode. However, it just showed a blank page with "AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined" error when running live.

I have read so many post relating to "AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined" issue. It seemed to be a problem that the ads has to be running on a separate thread to gain network access. However, if you move the loadAd and show methods to a new thread (like in [AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119062/afma-receivemessage-is-not-defined/34191785) or [Interstitial Admob doesn't work : AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906862/interstitial-admob-doesnt-work-afma-receivemessage-is-not-defined)), it will complain that it has to be run on the main thread!! Then if you use runOnUIThread method, then it will go back to the "AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined" problem.

I am really confused as they are conflicting solutions to each other. (It has to be run on the UIThread while it has to be on a separate thread to gain network access?)

Has anybody have a good working example to Interstitial Ads from admob (not in test mode)?